# SQL syntax error, number, date/time

Tags: mysql, syntax

This is producing an sql syntax error, don't know why:

```
INSERT INTO dnc_temp (number, release) VALUES ('07938347', '2014-07-10 23:50:12')
```

The fields I'm inserting into are INT(15) and DATETIME

Thanks

Comment: Lose the quotes from the integer value and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this <kbd>[**LIVE SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1942/1)</kbd>

column name **`release`** is [**`Reserve character`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) that's why **`producing syntax error`**. check Live SQLFiddle Link.

#### MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE dnc_temp(
  num INT(8),
  rel DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO dnc_temp (num, rel) VALUES ('07938347', '2014-07-10 23:50:12'); 

SELECT * FROM dnc_temp;
```

#### Result

```
NUM         REL
----------- ----------------------------
7938347     July, 10 2014 23:50:12+0000
```

Answer (score 2):

**[RELEASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)** is MySQL Reserved keyword

To use a reserved keyword as a column name use ` around the keyword

Try this :-

```
INSERT INTO dnc_temp (`number`, `release`) VALUES ('07938347', '2014-07-10 23:50:12')
```

Answer (score 0):

use the ` character to escape the reserved word "release".

```
INSERT INTO dnc_temp (number, `release`) VALUES ('07938347', '2014-07-10 23:50:12')
```