# MySql Database while Inserting Date

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-insert

I am using Mysql database to insert data from API in c# code. All other data can be inserted accept one field date.Below is my code

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO wpcommon.livingsocialoffers(id,uuid,title,starting) VALUES(@id,@uuid,@title,@starting)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "1599694");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uuid", "572a260d-bcd6-48fa-8ef9-c8faaf9d84d9");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", "testtitle");              
DateTime date= Convert.ToDateTime("6/2/2016 12:12:30 PM");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starting", date);                                
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

when  executes cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), its catching error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "(id,uuid,title,starting) VALUES(@id,@uuid,@title,@starting)"

I already used

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("STR_TO_DATE('@starting','%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')", date);
```

this error is occurred when I tried to insert date only.If I remove date from code its working fine.

Comment: try `DateTime.Parse` and consider using `Add` rather than `AddWithValue`

Comment: date is belongs to API, So i convert json string in to list of modal. the actual date from api is :  "2016-06-02T16:12:30+00:00" and after DeserializeObject i am getting "6/2/2016 12:12:30 PM" so i wrote final insert statement.I also tried only ADD but its catching same error

Comment: You likely need to parse the result to a NET DateTime: "6/2/2016" can be ambiguous between Jun 2, or Feb 6 depending on the culture

Comment: The default format in MySQL for dates is yyyy-MM-dd. That's how it avoids ambiguity.

Comment: Yea..let me see if it works.thanks @Plutonix ,derloopkat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I just need to out "**`**"  around date in sql insert statement. like **`starting`** Thant's all. 
Here is a reference link :

[SQL syntax error, number, date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179914/sql-syntax-error-number-date-time)